Are pull-up resistors required on SDRAM datalines?
I'm working with the eval/dev-kit of the RA8D1 MCU and the external memory bus on their schematic has 4.7K pull-ups on the 16-bit SDRAM data-lines.
 (from https://www.renesas.com/en/document/sch/ek-ra8d1-v1-design-package?r=25452351)
To be clear, these are pull ups and not series impedance matching resistors which are present on the address lines at 33Ohm.
Here's a similar design for RT1170 by NXP which does not show pull-ups or series resistors:
 from (https://www.nxp.com/design/design-center/development-boards-and-designs/i-mx-evaluation-and-development-boards/i-mx-rt1170-evaluation-kit:MIMXRT1170-EVKB)
What could be a reason they would add pull ups here?  Our design will not need the 74CBTLV3245BQ bus switches and I've only ever used series impedance matching resistors, not pull ups.
What is the correct way of doing this?

Generally speaking, pullups on SDRAM data lines are not required.
In practice, they are never tristated for long enough to get into trouble.
And unless you're very careful, the PCB trace stubs to the pullup resistors will cause more signal integrity problems than they solve.

Ok, thanks.  Did have concerns about the signal integrity, resistor arrays don't help either.

Which device is driving these lines when no transactions are taking place (for example, the bus might be accessing the internal SRAM, or Flash, and not the external SDRAM)?  I would have assumed that a microcontroller's memory expansion bus is tristated most of the time.  I definitely agree that the PCB layout shouldn't look like the schematic, with long stubs.

@BenVoigt: In general, an application that requires SDRAM at all tends to use it quite regularly, and rarely leaves it idle for more than a few milliseconds at a time. Which, as I said, is not long enough for a floating bus to get into any trouble.

EK-RA8D1 evaluation board
The EK-RA8D1 evaluation board from the question is designed such that the MCU signals needed for the SDRAM conflict with signals for the TRACE, ETH-A and Pmod 1 groups. This is why there are the 74CBTLV3245BQ bus switches U20, U21, U22, U23 and U24 between the IS42S16320F-6BLI SDRAM and MCU. Where a DIP switch is used to control the OE for the bus switches. That explains why the bus switches are used on the EK-RA8D1.
As noted by the other answer it is good practice to digital inputs not allowed to float. Depending upon the input structure voltages which float may cause extra power consumptions or inputs which oscillate.
On the EK-RA8D1 not all SDRAM signals are driven to a known state when the bus switches are disabled:

The data bus (DQ0 .. DQ15), chip select (CS), write enable (WE) and strobes (CAS and RAS) have pull-ups.
The address bus (A0 .. A12), bank selects (BA0 and BA1), clock enable (CKE), clock (CLK) and data strobes (DQMH and DQML) have no pull-ups and will therefore float.

The IS42S16320F datasheet indicates the SDRAM enters power-down mode when CKE is low, so by allowing CKE and CLK to float would allow the SDRAM to be in some undefined state.
I'm therefore not sure the EK-RA8D1 have only some SDRAM signals pulled to a defined state when the bus switches are disabled.
TMDSRM48HDK
TMDSRM48HDK Hercules RM48x Development Kit is another example of a MCU development board where the MCU pins can be shared between a SDRAM and other uses, and there is a jumper on the board to control the OE of a SN74CBTLV3245ARGY bus switch between the MCU and SDRAM.
For the TMDSRM48HDK example the schematic within the RM48 Hercules Development Kit (HDK) Board Design Files shows only a selection of the SDRAM signals which pass through the bus switch:



In the above only the following are passed through the bus switch:

DQMH, DQML and CS which have a pull-up so they are inactive when not driven.
CKE which has pull-down and are so inactive when not driven.

Summary
The pull-up / pull-down resistors on the bus switches between a MCU SDRAM controller and the SDRAM controller are a special case on a development board which allows MCU pins to be muxed between a SDRAM controller and other uses.
However, for a design where the RA8D1 MCU always uses the SDRAM and therefore doesn't need bus switches then don't think the pull-ups are necessary.

A memory data bus commonly idles with no driver.  The pull up ensures that the bus idles at a known and permissible voltage, instead of floating.  Digital inputs should never be allowed to float.
